# tidyverse: Selecting rows with same levels of a factor within each Year

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to select rows having same levels of `Let` within each `Year`.

```
library(tidyverse)

tb1 <- 
  tibble(
    Year = c(2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018)
  , Let  = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "D")
  , Y    = 1:6
  )

tb1
# A tibble: 6 x 3
   Year Let       Y
  <dbl> <chr> <int>
1  2017 A         1
2  2017 B         2
3  2017 C         3
4  2018 A         4
5  2018 B         5
6  2018 D         6
```

**Desired Output**

```
Year Let       Y
2017 A         1
2017 B         2
2018 A         4
2018 B         5
```

Any points/hints, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to first find the elements are `intersect`ing

```
library(tidyverse)
v1 <- Reduce(intersect,  split(tb1$Let, tb1$Year))
```

Or

```
v1 <- tb1 %>% 
         group_split(Year) %>%
         map(~ .x %>% pull(Let)) %>% 
         reduce(intersect)


 tb1 %>%
     filter(Let %in% v1)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#   Year Let       Y
#  <dbl> <chr> <int>
#1  2017 A         1
#2  2017 B         2
#3  2018 A         4
#4  2018 B         5
```

---

Or another option is `n_distinct` + `group_by`

```
tb1 %>% 
   group_by(Let) %>% 
   filter(n_distinct(Year) == n_distinct(tb1$Year))
```